# Arduino PWM program to generate a frequency in a loop

Tags: for-loop, audio, arduino, frequency, pwm

I am new to Arduino, and right now I am trying to generate a frequency that gradually decreases (without using the tone library) in a program that gradually increases the delay between the switching of the high and low. I have the arduino connected to an audio amp and a speaker.

For some reason, the speaker only outputs a single tone and I dont know why. Here is the code:

```
    void setup()
    {
      pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
    }

    void loop()
    {
      for (int i=100; i <= 25500; i+100){
        digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(i); 
        digitalWrite(3, LOW);
        delayMicroseconds(i);
      }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. I would prefer to try and do this the way I am doing, as opposed to using a completly different method or the tone library.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the `for` statement: the increment statement is actually not a [statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements). You need to assign `i` to the new value, i.e. write `i = i + 100` instead of just `i + 100`.